# Need to vertically align images beside div

Tags: alignment, html

### Heading

I need to align tags beside the price in featured products (the tags in the example feature the text "Aussie Made").

I need to vertically align the "Aussie Made" images beside the price (bottom align). The price can dynamically change in width and height. Can someone give me some ideas on how to make the "Aussie made" image/icon float on the right and still be on the bottom of the div aligned?

I tried to put 
**`position:absolute;
bottom:0px`** on the div containing the Aussie Made icon. However it didn't work. Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using position RELATIVE?
As in relative to the PARENT container?

Comment: Yeep tried that. I must be making some mistake somewhere. can someone show me which div should have the relative position and which should have the absolute please

Answer (score 0):

This should give you an ideia:

CSS

```
.container{position:relative; height:200px; width: 200px; outline: 1px solid #000; } 
.image { position: absolute; bottom:0px; right:0px; width: 10px; height: 10px; outline: 1px solid #000; }
```

HTML

`<div class="container"><div class="image"></div></div>`

Comment: aha got it fixed. Thanks guys :) ta

Answer (score 0):

I beg your pardon, your quite right, its ABSOLUTE not RELATIVE...
Although Absolute position actually makes the contents relative to the parent.

See the photo below.

[image]

and the code...

```
    <style type="text/css">
.Main
 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 400px;
  top: 200px;
  width: 469px; 
  height: 280px; 
 }
 .Photo
 {
  width: 469px; 
  height: 280px; 
  z-index: 1;
 }
 .Caption
 {
  position: absolute; 
  left: 0px;
  top: 250px;
  width: 461px; 
  height:32px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  background-color: #FF0000; 
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: tahoma; 
  font-size: 20pt; 
  text-align: left; 
  vertical-align: middle; 
  z-index: 2;
 }
 .Price
 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 330px;
  top: 215px;
  width: 122px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center; 
  vertical-align: middle; 
  z-index: 3;
  color: #CC3300; 
  font-size: 20pt; 
  background-color: #FFFF00;
 }
 .MiniText
 {
  top: 4px;
  color: #111111;
  font-size: 8pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Tahoma;
 }
</style>
<div style="left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 800px;">
 <div class="Main">
  <img class="Photo" alt="" src="http://202.92.83.79/medias/sys_master/images/8796157247518/Package-img1.jpg" />
  <div class="Price" style="z-index: 4">
   <div class="MiniText">First of it's kind!</div>
    £100.97p
         </div>
        <div class="Caption" style="z-index: 3">Sooper Dooper Wotsit Thingy</div>
 </div>
</div>
```